# Error while running Jprofile8

Tags: jprofiler

I am getting following error while running /tmp/jprofiler8/bin/jpenable

No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
The version of the JVM must be at least 1.6 and at most 1.7.
Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.
You can also try to delete the JVM cache file

I have also set INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to suitable JVM.

Java version on my machine is 1.4.2.

Can anyone please suggest what might be wrong or missing?

Comment: Is installing Java 8 something you can't do ?

Comment: I can't update the java version.

Comment: would it be possible to simply unzip a current Java version near to the installer and reference that one during installation ? This would safe you from having to install it. But one problem remains: which version does the code you profile run in ? Even if you get JProfiler installed I think you will have trouble profiling an application on Java 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you did not mention details about your environment, so I don't know which Linux distribution you use.

There are some options though:

1. install a current JRE alongside the installer for JProfiler

As you can't install or update Java, you could provide a JRE in a kind of "portable application" setup. Simply unzip the server jre [Oracle provides](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html) or (if you are not on an x64 architecture) unzip the jdk you also can [download from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

But if the code you want to profile is limited to your pre-installed Java 1.4 you will run into another problem, because as far as I know Java 1.5 is the minimum [JProfiler expects](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/featuresPlatforms.html)

2. use a different machine for profiling

Unless your code depends heavily on the environment you run it in you can even take a Windows 8.1 machine and profile the code there. Code that is slow is slow on any operating system. Or make use of a different Linux computer.